# ajax only sends the first value of input and not the others?

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax

I made a school website where teachers will be able to upload the students' marks. Up to now I have these three files:

The first one, will display every students name depending on the subject and course

```
<table class="check">
    <tr class="arrow">
        <th>Student</th>
        <th>Add Mark</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach(var users in user){
    <tr class="arrow">
        <td>@users.Nombre @users.Apellido</td>
        <td>
            <form method="post">
                <input type="text" id="user" style="display: none" name="user" @Validation.For("nombre") value="@users.UserId" />
                       <input type="text" id="galleryId" style="display: none" name="galleryId" @Validation.For("nombre") value="@galleryId" />
                       <input type="text" id="note" name="button2" name="note" @Validation.For("nombre") />
                       <input type="button"   value="Ready" title="Ready" onclick="loco(document.getElementById('user').value, document.getElementById('galleryId').value, document.getElementById('note').value)" />
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Here you can see that I used `foreach` to display every student's name, and then next to it there should be displayed an input textbox for the teacher to write the mark of a specific student. That's why I included the form in the `foreach`.

Next is the ajax file:

```
function loco(user, gallery, note) {
    var xmlhttp;
    var user = document.getElementById("user").value;
    var galleryid = document.getElementById("galleryId").value;
    var note = document.getElementById("note").value;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "/Marks/add1/" + gallery + "/" + user + "/" + note, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

And finally, we have the page which will insert the marks to the database without returning any table or div, just uploading the mark.

```
@{
    var db2 = Database.Open("ica");
    var user = UrlData[1];
    var galleryId = UrlData[0];
    var note = UrlData[2].AsInt();
    db2.Execute("INSERT INTO Notas (Nota, UserId, Sub_Id) VALUES (@0, @1, @2)", note, user, galleryId);
}
```

So, why does the ajax send the values of the first student to the upload file and not the second, third, etc? Why, when I click on the submit button of the second student does it sends the mark of the first student again, and only that of the first student?

Comment: `var user = document.getElementById("user").value;
    var galleryid = document.getElementById("galleryId").value;
    var note = document.getElementById("note").value;`

remove this from function it is useless there

Answer (score 2):

You're using hard-coded IDs in the HTML inside your for-each loop, so you're going to get multiple elements on your page with the same IDs for `user`, `galleryId` and `note`. That means that your selector can only select the first no matter which you're actually trying to use. You need to do something such as adding an index number to the end of the ID instead of fully hard-coded IDs, so that they can be distinguished from one another.

Comment: I thought of writting on the form the line id="somthing(user.UserId)" which would result in something like: id="someting1" ... id="someting2"... etc.. Do I have to modify the Uploader file? the one that uploads the marks?

Comment: I'm not really clear what you mean... but wherever you edit it, you just need to make sure that you don't have non-unique IDs. The way I would do it offhand would be to just add a bit more C# to your cshtml file so that you create an index value which you can increment during each pass through the for-each loop, and tack that index number onto the end of the IDs. There's other ways you could handle it though it's up to you. You just need unique strings.

Comment: Yea it was a little confusing what I said, but basically I could make each form´s ID to have a number at the end that increases through each loop. Once I have that, do I have to change something else from any of the other files? because I am having the same results unfortunately

Comment: Yeah, you should remove the lines 
    var user = document.getElementById("user").value;
    var galleryid = document.getElementById("galleryId").value;
    var note = document.getElementById("note").value;
from the loco function, and make sure that the IDs you're passing into it from the button's onclick function are those of the correct elements from that iteration of the loop. You just need to look at all your code and make sure that all your unique IDs are being used in the appropriate places.

Comment: check my answer...do the changes accordingly @user3622058

Comment: If my answer served as a good explanation of the issue, I'd love if you'd accept it!

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE:**

I observed you using name multiple times in same input please remove that:

```
<input type="text" id="note" name="button2" name="note" @Validation.For("nombre") />
```

here you gave name as `button2` as well `note` please remove `button2`

**Make the changes as below:**

```
function loco(form) {
    var xmlhttp;
    var user = form.name.value;
    var gallery = form.galleryId.value;
    var note = form.note.value;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "/Marks/add1/" + gallery + "/" + user + "/" + note, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    return false;
}
```

**change your html related code as below:**

```
<form onsubmit="return loco(this)">
    <input type="text" id="user" style="display: none" name="user" @Validation.For("nombre") value="@users.UserId" />
    <input type="text" id="galleryId" style="display: none" name="galleryId" @Validation.For("nombre") value="@galleryId" />
    <input type="text" id="note" name="note" @Validation.For("nombre") />
    <input type="submit" value="Ready" title="Ready" />
</form>
```